# upgrade sonar and import all existing project matrix

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

we would like to upgrade from Sonar 3.0 to 3.5. we have many project profiles/matrix in the current sonar and if possible to import existing project matrix, build data and time machine data into the new sonar. How do i export current data and make them visible in Sonar 3.5?

Tried to upgrade in my testing machine and turned out Sonar page is empty. I followed all the Sonar upgrade guide including backup. It is important for us to keep existing project build and trending matrix(time machien).

btw, i'm using mysql.

Answer (score 0):

When using Sonar with DBs like Oracle, MySql, Postgres or MSSQL, the migration process keeps everything already in place and you should end up with the same state as it was before the migration. If this is not the case, this means that the migration went wrong and you should be able to see it in the logs.

Comment: sonar successfully upgraded. only that the project data all gone. How do i retrieve back the old history data?

Comment: Well I hope you were wise enough to performe a backup of your DB, so you can replay the migration. And I confirm that you can NOT loose data during a successful migration.

Comment: old project data displayed after drop and re-create back sonar db. thanks for developing such a great tool.